# How to write to AppName-Info.plist

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

i added a key called "App" to my AppName-Info.plist manually , i can get the value from it by calling this code

```
NSBundle *mainBundle;
mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *value = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"App"];

NSLog(@"App: %@",value);
```

But what i couldn't do is changing the value with any code.. is it possible ? and if yes how can it be done ?

thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Because the info-plist file is read-only (?). Anyway wait for other's answer

Comment: means you want to change the App object value that is in your info.plist if this no as i think

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :)

Comment: If one of the answers already fulfilled your question, consider about checking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or if you want to modify a bundled .plist  try this.

```
    NSString* plistFilePath = nil;
NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ((plistFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mySpecial/PathTo.plist"])) 
{
    if ([manager isWritableFileAtPath:plistFilePath]) 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* infoDictioio = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
        [infoDictio setObject:@"foo object" forKey:@"fookey"];
        [infoDictio writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:NO];
        [manager setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDate date] forKey:NSFileModificationDate] ofItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: downvotes (and upvotes) really should come with comments - I admit I dont always comment up votes...

Comment: but some times without comments as many with me.. :) anyways it's k i share something and some got it this is more important :)

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, AppName-Info.plist is not included in the bundle and is therefore not writable. However, Info.plist is included and writable. And that case, this methods works well.

Answer (score 2):

You should not modify your apps Info.plist file (or anything in your app's bundle) at runtime. This is bad practice and will also break your bundles code signature (which will result in not being able to launch the app anymore!).

If you want to store settings you should have a look at [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/).

Comment: Breaking the bundle's code signature by modifying the info.plist is explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

By default the AppName-Info.plist isn't copied into the bundle in the Copy Bundle Resources phase of the build.

So if you want to have a plist which you can write to an option would be to create it at run time in the temporary files location and read/write to it there.

[This](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html) is a great place to research how to do it.