# Write dynamically content to xCode project .plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist, nsbundle

I would like to copy/update some content within an existing iOS application `.plist` dynamically.

For instance, the `.plist` contains the FacebookAppID or Twitter API Key I would like to update over time without having to re-deploy the application on the store.

I know I could copy the `.plist` from the `NSBundle` to the `NSDocumentsDirectory` to make it writable.
But the newly copied file is not the one the OS will use to access the information I need to change over time.
Because of the SDKs (FBSDK among others) rely solely on the property file, I can't use other ways to store the key/values I am interested in.

Any idea?

Comment: So the SDK's use a fixed `.plist` file located at a fixed location within the app bundle?  If that's true then there is nothing you can do and the SDKs are broken.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't believe that is true as no-one is that stupid.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for your feedback. Actually the FB SDK relies on the .plist as shown in their get started : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/
And there is no API within the SDK to set it programatically.

Comment: @trojanfoe actually looks like I might be mistaken : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/constants/FBSDKSettings/

Comment: @trojanfoe Actually it looks like the appID and appDisplayName can be changed dynamically, but we stil have to set in advance the URL Scheme in the .plist to make callbacks possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to edit the App-Info.plist file at run-time (please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924921/how-to-write-to-appname-info-plist)).

For Facebook SDK, you just need to set your AppID in your App-Info.plist, but the AppID is not subject to change everyday (same for Twitter). If you need to link another app, you'll need to push an update of your app.

If you have several apps (eg. one for production and one for testing), create several targets with a separate .plist file for each one, so that you can switch AppID depending on the target you build.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it during runtime.

But you can do it dynamically during build time.

1. In Xcode go into Build Settings set Preprocess Info.plist File to YES
2. Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File to a .h file you've placed in your project with #define directives.

Use a .h file to include the values you want to put into the plist.

```
#ifdef DEVELOPMENT

#define FACEBOOK_APP_ID             @"00000000"
#define FACEBOOK_APP_URL            @"fb00000000"
#define FACEBOOK_APP_NAME           @"App Display Name - Test"
#define FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET         @"abcdef00000000"

#else

#define FACEBOOK_APP_ID             @"00000001"
#define FACEBOOK_APP_URL            @"fb00000001"
#define FACEBOOK_APP_NAME           @"App Display Name"
#define FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET         @"abcdef00000001"

#endif
```

And then in info.plist, do the following

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>FACEBOOK_APP_ID</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>FACEBOOK_APP_NAME</string>
```

You cannot do it during runtime. But hope this will at least save you sometime in doing all the configurations for your project updates.