# Allow HTTP without disabling ATS in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, app-transport-security

I am developing an app which have a small tweak in it. it will show a preview of the given url (like Facebook,whatsapp does). but if the "User-given" url is in HTTP, I couldn't load the preview when ATS is turned on. so i turned off the whole HTTPS traffic by using **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** . is there any way to allow http with ATS enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33), if you build against an older SDK, so iOS 8 or earlier, then ATS is disabled. I don't know exactly what this means, but I'm guessing it is the target build setting Architectures, Base SDK -- not the deployment target setting.

[This video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/) has details of changes to ATS recently announced at WWDC 2016. As of the start of 2017, Apple will reject your app if you're using any of the following ATS exceptions **AND** you can't provide a reasonable justification for doing so:

- NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
- NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
- NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion

However, it appears you **will** be allowed to use a new exception called:

- NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent

which means that **a WKWebView control** can still load HTTP content. Not sure if this applies to UIWebView as well.

In your case, I'm guessing you're not using a WKWebView, so you'd better start working on your "reasonable justification". Or stick with the iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: How are you planning to generate the previews? With a WKWebView control? If so, wait for Apple to release NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent and use that. Otherwise, can you generate the previews on the server and send them to your app as an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can add exceptions (`NSExceptionDomains`) to allow HTTP for specific domains. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33).

However, if the user given URL can be any URL, then there is no other way but to use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`.

Comment: i've tried intercept Facebook ios app traffic with burp-proxy and the traffic is going through HTTPS, but they still showing the previews for HTTP links. they are not skipping ATS . that means there's some way to do this. isn't?

Comment: @Duke Yes there is a way - use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`.

Comment: I'm trying to do like the way facebook did. Allow HTTP with SSL (ATS).

Comment: @Duke You're not making any sense. HTTP with SSL is HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry for made you lost :D . `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`  makes my app completely HTTP/transparent in network layer and anyone can sniff what's going through in the traffic. I don't want to disable ATS for the whole app for this tiny tweak (Preview for links) . is there any way to disable ATS for that feature only?

Comment: @Duke `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` simply allows HTTP. HTTPS would still be secure. It does not make apps "transparent in the network layer".

Comment: Just think of ATS as a set of restrictions which prevents insecure connections from being made. Basically it is Apple forcing everyone to use HTTPS with TLSv1.2 and FS. Switching ATS off just removes those restrictions, and allows your app to do whatever it likes -- to use a mixture of secure and insecure connections.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Info.plist` as Source Code, then add this where you want :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>aWebsite.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
            <key>anotherWebsiteIfYouWant.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

This way you won't have to disable ATS totally.

Comment: We don't know the user input. it can be any HTTP url

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. You can see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924921/how-to-write-to-appname-info-plist) on how to write to info.plist during runtime but I'm not sure about that...